# using forward slash as matching pattern in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a `textarea` where user types his codes and a `div` tag where it renders how it will be displayed on a webpage. I am using custom tags to format user codes like `[b]bold text[/b]` instead of `<b>bold text </b>` i am using `string.replace()` function to replace custom tag with original to tag preview user codes. But how can use forward slash(`/`) as matching pattern

i have already gone though couples of know method . i have tried

```
string.replace(/[\/b]/gi,"</b>");
string.replace(/[\x2Fb]/gi,"</b>");
string.replace(/[\x2F b]/gi,"</b>");
```

Here is code how i am really doing it in my project

```
//Helper Function
function $(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
//Helper Variables//

//Display Preview of question
function render(){//
    var question_content = $("question_content").value;
    //Sanitizing data//
    var entitles = {//List of all Html entitles & custum entitles
        '<':"&lt;",
        '>':"&gt;",
        '\n':"<br>",
        '[b]':"<b>",
        '[/b]':"</b>",
        '[i]':"<i>",    
        '[/i]':"</i>",
        '[code]':"<code class='prettyprint'>",
        '[/code]':"</code>"         
    }
    question_content = question_content.replace(/<|>|\n|[b]|[\/b]/gi, function (html_ent){return entitles[html_ent];});
    //question_content = question_content.replace(/'/, "</b>");
    var preview = $("preview");
    preview.innerHTML = question_content;   
    //prettyPrint();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the first approach would have worked if you didn't forget about escaping brackets:

```
string.replace(/\[\/b]/gi,"</b>");
```

Only the opening one should be escaped, though; regex engine is smart enough to differentiate between `]` as a literal symbol and as a metasymbol (that closed that character class subexpression).

Overall, you can simplify your code by using something like this:

```
var codes = ['b', 'i', 'code'];
// here goes a little hack to enable special decoration for some elements
codes.code = 'class="prettyprint"';

var string = 'abc[b]abc[/b]da[code]s[/code][something]d';
string.replace(/\[(\/?)([a-z]+)]/gi, function(m, p1, p2) {
  return codes.indexOf(p2) !== -1 
  ? '<' + p1 + p2 + (!p1 && p2 in codes ? ' ' + codes[p2] : '') + '>'
  : m
});
```

It's certainly possible to express the same algorithm with a dictionary (object), like this:

```
var decorators = { 
  b: '', i: '', 
  code: 'class="prettyprint"'
};

var string = 'abc[b]abc[/b]da[code]s[/code][something]d';
string.replace(/\[(\/?)([a-z]+)]/gi, function(m, p1, p2) {
  return p2 in decorators 
    ? '<' + p1 + p2 + 
      (!p1 && decorators[p2] ? ' ' + decorators[p2] : '') + '>'
    : m;
});
```